processing sec-edgar 10k filings on python
I want to pre-process and merge 10-K filings from multiple companies over a span of ten years for data visualization. The files I have downloaded are in .txt format. How can I download them in a format that can be processed?
def download_10k_filings(ticker, company_name):
    dl = Downloader(company_name, "mail@email.com")

    try:
        dl.get("10-K", ticker, limit=29)
        print(f"Downloaded 10-K filing for {ticker} ({company_name}) ")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error downloading 10-K filing for {ticker} ({company_name}): {e}")

companies = ["PANW", "DIS", "NFLX"]  # Ticker symbols
company_names = ["Palo Alto Network", "Disney", "Netflix"]  

for i in range(3):
    download_10k_filings(companies[i], company_names[i])

